# What is the best word to describe popularity that does not stay the same through the years?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is the best word (except for changing) to describe popularity that does not stay the same over the years? For example, a movie was once popular. Then it fell out of favor. And then again it became popular.

---

The following example sentence was added *after* one of the answers below was provided.

---

"The movie has had ...... popularity since it was first released in 1982. It became a surprise box office hit, but suddenly after a couple of years it slid into oblivion and it was not until the early 2010s that it regained its popularity."

Comment: Please give the sentence that you wish to use but leave a blank for the missing word.

Comment: @Greybeard - Added the context.

Comment: Many thanks, very helpful. I would say "The movie has had changing fortunes ..." but you could say "variable popularity"

Comment: @Nick08 I edited your question to make it clear that your edit wasn't part of the original version. Without that being made clear, the answer **ups and downs** does not fit the example sentence without some additional changes. I actually downvoted it before I realized what had happened. At the time before your edit, it was a very good answer.

Comment: Please include your research: what words did you consider, and why did these not suit your needs?

Comment: The movie's popularity has fluctuated over the years.

Comment: in favor, out of favor

Answer (score 2):

How about **ups and downs**? From Lexico:

> **[ups and downs](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ups_and_downs)** (pl. n.): Rises and falls, especially in the value or success of something.

From M-W:

> **[ups and downs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ups%20and%20downs)** (pl. n.): alternating rise and fall especially in fortune

Another possibility is **rollercoaster ride**. From Lexico:

> **[rollercoaster ride](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rollercoaster_ride)** (n.): A journey or experience of extreme and rapid changes.

Both answers could work, depending on the context, but I would say **ups and downs** works best for your "movie" example.

**Addendum**: Many thanks to @JasonBassford for pointing out that the OP has added an example sentence. The OP's example sentence with the answers suggested above:

> The movie has had its **ups and downs** (in popularity) since it was first released in 1982. It became a surprise box office hit, but suddenly after a couple of years it slid into oblivion and it was not until the early 2010s that it regained its popularity."
>
> The movie has had a **rollercoaster ride** (in popularity) since it was first released in 1982. It became a surprise box office hit, but suddenly after a couple of years it slid into oblivion and it was not until the early 2010s that it regained its popularity."

Comment: To fit those terms into the now existing example sentence, you would use (1) "the movie has had *ups and downs* ***in*** popularity …" or (2) "the movie has ***been a*** *rollercoaster ride* ***of*** popularity …"

Answer (score 1):

How about the word "fluctuating"?

In [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fluctuating), it gives:

> Fluctuating describes something that has unpredictable ups and downs. Fluctuating often refers to changing numbers or quantities of something, like fluctuating stock prices that go up and down.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from linked references to support your claim (say an online dictionary). Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: Thanks, I added one.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard Kayser and auspicious99 have already provided good answers but I still offer up a word and an expression.

**[Oscillating](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oscillate)** would also work in the examples you have given.

Expression: **[Wax and wane](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wax-and-wane)**.

"The movie has waxed and waned in popularity".